# Autocorrelation and GLS

Tags: regression, autocorrelation, generalized-least-squares

If autocorrelation in a model is detected by the Breusch-Godfrey test for r-th order autocorrelation, what is the GLS procedure for "fixing" the autocorrelation problem? And is Cochrane-Orcutt procedure a part of the GLS method, or is it a separate "remedy" for autocorrelation?

Answer (score 4):

GLS is the *model* that takes autocorrelated residuals into account, while Cochrane-Orcutt is one of the many *procedures* to estimate such GLS model.

Strictly speaking, the GLS model requires the true value of $\rho$ in $\varepsilon_t = \rho\varepsilon_{t-1} + w_t$ to be known. However, apparently $\rho$ is unobservable. Cochrane-Orcutt is one (of many) iterative procedures to estimate $\rho$ and the GLS model. ([a random reference/further reading](https://isi-rsc2017.org/Portal/Proceeding/CPS/ISIRSC2017_CPS15_S2_P_Langoyan.pdf))

GLS is not the only way to fix the autocorrelated residual problem. For example, adding lagged terms of dependent/independent variables as predictors to the OLS may also fix the problem, depends on the true relationship among the variables.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is known generally as a Transfer Function sometimes as a Dynamic Regression [How to forecast a time series which is dependent on different time series?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251160/how-to-forecast-a-time-series-which-is-dependent-on-different-time-series) . You might want to also look at [ARIMAX model's exogenous components?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82782/arimax-models-exogenous-components) and [An example of autocorrelation in residuals causing misinterpretation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145099/an-example-of-autocorrelation-in-residuals-causing-misinterpretation/167772#167772).

Comment: Really? Is that considered a GLS procedure? I was expecting something else under that title.

Comment: GLS raises two possible issues ..

Comment: Yes, it also appeared to me that making the regression dynamic with adding lags to the dependent variable is a way to fix autocorrelation, but isn't it a separate procedure from the GLS?

Comment: The idea behind GLS raises two possible issues .. 1) non-constancy of diagonal elements suggesting weighted least squares or some sort of power transform  &  2) non-zero elements in the off-diagonal elements suggesting possibly omitted lag structure for one of the user-specified stochastic X's or ARIMA structure effectively dealing with omitted lag structure for the Y series . https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=generalized+least+squares and http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/~wsosa/econ507/gls.pdf

Comment: I think Transfer function modelling is not a special case of GLS as it requires maximum likelihood estmation rather than feasible GLS (which is a different estimation method). So I think you answer does not address the question that is being asked.

Comment: you can estimate a tf using exact lilelihood

Comment: Exactly. The question is about GLS, your answer deals with maximum likelihood. I fail to see the connection...